# Pandas as_matrix() with entire groupby() result

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, pandas-groupby

I know that I can make an SQL-like sum on groupby in Pandas with

```
output = pd.read_csv("file.csv").groupby(['cat1', 'cat2']).sum()
```

I want this output as a numpy array, but when I try `output.as_matrix()` or `output.values`, these only provide the aggregate sum column. How to I get the matrix with cat1, cat2, and the sum as a numpy array?

For example, `output` could be something like

```
Cat1 Cat2  Sum
---- ----  ---
Mon  Sunny  25
Tue  Rainy  15
Sun  Cloudy 32
```

I want to extract what you see above as a matrix, but `as_matrix()` only provides the sum column.

Comment: Can you add some sample data and expected output?

Comment: Do you think `output = pd.read_csv("file.csv").groupby(['cat1', 'cat2'], as_index=False).sum().values` or `output = pd.read_csv("file.csv").groupby(['cat1', 'cat2']).sum().reset_index().values` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to convert `Series` with `MultiIndex` to `DataFrame` - with parameter `as_index=False` in [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) or by [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.reset_index.html):

```
output = pd.read_csv("file.csv").groupby(['cat1', 'cat2'], as_index=False).sum().values 

output = pd.read_csv("file.csv").groupby(['cat1', 'cat2']).sum().reset_index().values
```